# can anyone help me with the html pattern validation for a string of 6 chracters?

Tags: html

can anyone help me with the html pattern for validating a string which has its first letter as "C" ,second letter as either "A" or "S" followed by four numbers.(Eg: cs4567,ca1589)

Comment: pattern="c+[s]{1}|[a]{1}+[0-9]{4}"

Answer (score 3):

The pattern is supposed to be a regex, and your question indicated case insensitivity, so the following will work:

`^[Cc][AaSs][0-9]{4}$`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean RegExp? And perhaps instead of "letters" you mean "numbers".

```
/^c[as]?\d{4}$/i
```

Comment: Your regex will allow abca123456789.

Comment: Fixed. I didn't realise he wanted "invalidate strings that are not...". He phrased it in the positive.

Subtle difference, but there you go ;-) What you're suggesting is probably more in line with what he *means* ;-)

Comment: Agreed. Equally, he didn't specify that he requires case insensitivity, when he clearly does